# How should I combine completable futures and try/catch in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I have a method that combines the results of two other methods, one which is synchronous and throws an exception if something goes wrong, and one which returns a completable future, which completes with an exception if something goes wrong. I would like the consumer of my method to not have to deal with catching synchronous and async exceptions in two separate places, is there a decent way I can combine them into one exception output?

Comment: Does the outer method return an immediate result or a future?

Comment: I'd like it to return a future, so it's non blocking. But I'm open to recommendations on return type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your outer method to return a `CompletableFuture`, then it's usually best if it *always* returns a `CompletableFuture` -- no throws and no nulls.

That way, the caller only has to handle exceptions or nulls through one path.

When the outer method makes the synchronous call, make sure it's in a `try` block, catch any exception and return an exceptionally completed `CompletableFuture` for it.

If you're using java 9 or better, you can use `CompletableFuture.failedFuture` to make the error future.  Otherwise you should probably make a helper method that makes a new future and calls `completeExceptionally` on it right away.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to wrapping the synchronous method call into a `CompletableFuture` as suggested by [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56046823/402428) there is [`CompletableFuture.thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose(java.util.function.Function)) for composing the results of the two individual futures.